# Can not save Translation Manager specifics

Tags: 2013, translation-manager

I am unable to add Translation Manager details within publication properties. When I add the details and hit save, the save notification quickly pops up, then disappears. The notification then remains in the notification center indefinitely, but the properties window remains open and the updates do not save.

I have checked the Translation Manager & CME logs, as well as the event viewer and nothing is standing out as the cause.

I can make a different update, such as update publication metadata and save the properties successfully, but as soon as I try to add translation details it stops working.

[image: Publication Properties]

Comment: Could you try checking for JavaScript or server errors in your browser's developer console (F12)? My assumption is that something has gone wrong with the installation of TM and you are getting server-side errors from IIS (which won't be logged by TM then).